# new to google apps scripting I'm looking to open a file and retrieve email address and folder name

Tags: file, variables

I need to via google apps script open a file to get email address and a folder name for over 1000 different users and add to a variable to use for other parts of code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function myFunction() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Folder ID");
    var theRange = ss.getDataRange()
    number = (theRange.getA1Notation());
    var theManualRange = ss.getRange(number);
    var vals = theManualRange.getValues();
for(i=0; i<vals.length; i++) {
    var name = vals[i][0];
    var folder = vals[i][1];
    Logger.log(name + "  " + folder);
    }
 }
```